# Whats the best windows tool for merging RSS Feeds?

Tags: rss, merge

It seems like such a simple thing, but I can't find any obvious solutions...

I want to be able to take two or three feeds, and then merge then in to a single rss feed, to be published internally on our network.

Is there a simple tool out there that will do this? Free or commercial..

update: Should have mentioned, looking for a windows application that will run as a scheduled service on a server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a whole pile of options here: http://allrss.com/rssremixers.html.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe http://www.planetplanet.org/
will do what you want.

It's for creating blog aggregations like [planet lisp](http://planet.lisp.org/).

Comment: Planet Planet is very nice if you want to turn the RSS feeds into a single website. It can be set up in 20 minutes or so once you have Python installed.

Answer (score 1):

Google reader, create a group, add your feeds into the folder and then share that as an RSS feed.

:-)

Works while you're asleep!

Answer (score 1):

[Yahoo Pipes](http://pipes.yahoo.com/) could be nice. Depends on how much "private" you want the resulting feed to be.

For 100% offline solution investigate [Atomisator](http://tarekziade.wordpress.com/2008/08/20/atomisator-a-framework-to-build-custom-rss-feeds/). It's a Python framework basically for doing offline what Yahoo Pipes does online.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using PHP, the [SimplePie](http://simplepie.org/) library will do this.  [Here's a tutorial](http://www.webmaster-source.com/2007/08/06/merging-rss-feeds-with-simplepie/).